# Commits disappeared from master

Tags: git

I did a merge back to master from my branch. All seemed ok then. Someone from my team tried to do a revert and I dunno what happened but there was no delta revert. It was as if my commits had never been made. I need to reapply these commits. A `git show hash` still shows my commit data. How can I reapply this to master?

Comment: They did a revert on your repository or on a remote (that you pushed to).

Comment: Sounds like your team worker forced "master" to point elsewhere instead of mergin.

Comment: which command you used to merge your branch to master?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a git checkout -b at your latest commit (the latest one you think you've lost), then try to merge back to your master branch.